# Unity crashes at Get- Call in RestSharp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, get, restsharp

I use RestSharp to send post and get calls to a robot which is connected via LAN through a switch with my computer. My get call:

```
public Vector3 getEffectorPos() 
{
    var c = new RestClient("http://" + robotIP);
    var r = new RestRequest("/present/effector_position.json", Method.GET);
    List<String> queryResult = c.Execute<List<String>>(r).Data;
    string[] tmp = queryResult[0].Split('[', ']');
    Vector4 x = parseStringToFloat4(tmp[2]);
    Vector4 y = parseStringToFloat4(tmp[4]);
    Vector4 z = parseStringToFloat4(tmp[6]);
    Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x.w, y.w, z.w);
    effPos.setPos(x.w, y.w, z.w);
    effPos.cos = x.x;
    effPos.sin = -x.y;
    return pos;
}
```

Because the robot has the static ip 192.168.200.99 I have to switch to a static ip adress in the .200 subnet every time I want to run the project. When I first started the project I would get an error like NullReference or Bad Gateway if the robot was not connected.

But now if I forget to switch from dynamic ip to a static one and the programm can't connect to the robot Unity crashes. And afterwards even if I switch back to a static ip Unity proceeds to crash and it seems like nothing helps but waiting and after some time it will just work again without me doing anything.

It seems like I don't have the same problem with the post call:

```
    public bool postEffectroPos(Vector3 pos, float speed_n)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://" + robotIP);
        var request = new RestRequest("/present/effector_position_with_speed.json", Method.POST) { RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json };
        effectorPos a = new effectorPos();
        a.x = pos.x;
        a.y = pos.y;
        a.z = pos.z;
        a.speed = speed_n;
        request.AddBody(a);
        bool move = false;
        try
        {
            client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        string[] tmp = response.Content.Split(':');
                        string t = tmp[1].Remove(tmp[1].Length - 1);
                        move = bool.Parse(t);
                        //Debug.Log(move);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Log(response.StatusCode);
                    }
                });
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Debug.Log(error);
        }
        return move;
    }
```

The post call is async but I didn't figure out yet how to a return a value with async(returns always zero or false, depending on type) and I need the return value of the get call.